# Forcing Azure AD login prompt for SAML

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I am using the Google Cloud connector application in Azure so that my organisation can login to their auto provisioned G Suite accounts with their Azure AD account.

An inconvenience of this setup is that it is now basically impossible to sign in to multiple G Suite accounts because there's this login loop - whenever you try to sign in to a different Azure AD account on the G Suite login page it automatically signs you in with the currently logged in AAD account and does not prompt you if you want to use another account etc.

Demo of what this sort of behaviour looks like - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/2388498?key=4e3527ba1445fdd0c28fefebeca8ef6a (not my video but exact same issue)

Is there a way to prompt the AAD account selection prompt or force reauthentication somehow? Supplying a login hint would work but G Suite doesn't autopopulate that when it sends the SAML request and using prompt=force doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 1):

•   Your issue is a result of the access token being cached while logging in to the Google workspace using Azure AD identities as they use MSAL for authentication purposes. Thus, when login is successful for a user account, the access token is cached in the browser storage.

•   As the access token is cached in the browser storage, it first calls the ‘AcquireTokenSilent’ method to verify if an acceptable token is in the cache or not due to which when a new tab or window is opened, the same token is used for logging in to the platform and thus, the same account is logged in to the platform even though you enter the credentials for other account.

•   Please find the below diagram for detailed token authorization flow: -

[image: Token Autorization flow]

•   You can try clearing the cache and cookies of the browser when logging in to the Google workspace with another account. Also, you can open a window in incognito mode to login to the Google workspace with another account simultaneously as the access token will be generated afresh for that account login in the browser storage since attempting to silently get a token will acquire another token with more scopes based on a token in the cache.

•   Thus, please refer the below links for more information on this scenario: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-clear-token-cache

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens